# Unable to Login to Custom CentOS created using Kickstart

Tags: centos, kickstart

The following is my kickstart configuration file:

```
#version=RHEL7
# System authorization information
auth --enableshadow --passalgo=sha512
# Use CDROM installation media
cdrom
# Run the Setup Agent on first boot
firstboot --enable
ignoredisk --only-use=vda
# Keyboard layouts
keyboard --vckeymap=us --xlayouts='us'
# System language
lang en_US.UTF-8
# Root password
rootpw qwerty
# Install Repo
repo --name="CentOS Repo" --baseurl=http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/Linux/CentOS/7/os/x86_64/
# System timezone
timezone America/New_York --isUtc
# System bootloader configuration
bootloader --location=mbr --boot-drive=vda
autopart --type=lvm
# Partition clearing information
clearpart --none --initlabel
%packages
@core
%end
%post
mkdir -p /etc/sample
mkdir danis
echo "Hello World" >> danis.txt
touch /var/danis.txt
%end
```

I created an ISO for installing using the following command.

```
sudo livecd-creator --verbose --config=ks.cfg --fslabel=DanisCentOS --cache=/var/cache/live
```

The ISO creation completes successfully, but when I try to login to the OS after installing it, it asks me for a password which doesn't match the password I set. Nor am I allowed to login with any password. Please help.

Comment: Hmm, the RedHat installation guide is unclear what the default is for `rootpw`. Try changing it to `rootpw --plaintext qwerty` to be explicit?

Comment: @thrig Hey, I tried this. Still not able to login.

Comment: what about `rootpw --iscrypted $6$/oYzqazdmaL0dSdx$enlSyv1K2kxe/azYsqaeJeyPDMAVr1UjFL2Fnvk.Af0lWgxpSo42ORn65TGIo6fiygt2GlVzo5cdl5gKZYyvY1` (or another option would be to single user mode boot with `init=/bin/bash` and look at what's gotten written to the disk post-install...